# How to search a string from backwards in php?

Tags: php

```
$str="This is a string with <xref cite@#>test</xref> and 
<xref cite@#>string2</xref>";
```

I need to get the string between "@#>test" and "xref ".

I tried:

```
$start=strpos($str,"@#>test");
$end=strpos($str,"xref ",$start); //here how to search backwards from  "@#>test"
//to "xref "
```

**Expected output:**
cite

strrpos - only for getting last occurrence of a string.Is there any function to search the string backwards from the position specified?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Note the difference between strpos() and str**r**pos). The extra **r** stands for reverse.

Comment: What do you mean by first occurrence? Could you explain clearly?

Comment: What is the complete expected output? You said you need "cite", but do you need to replace it? What do you need to do with it?

Comment: I need content between "xref  "and "@#>test" .From the content, I will do further scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**  by regex `(?<=xref).*(?=@#)`

```
$re = "/(?<=xref).*(?=@#)/m";
$str = "This is a string with <xref cite@#>test</xref> and \n<xref cite@#>test</xref>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Live demo][1]

**Update:**  `(?<=<xref).*?(?=@#)`

```
$re = "/(?<=<xref).*?(?=@#)/m";
$str = "This is a string with <xref cite@#>test2</xref> and <xref cite@#>test1</xref><xref cite@#>test</xref><xref cite@#>test1</xref>\n<xref cite<e.g.>[p.11]@#>test</xref>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Update link](https://regex101.com/r/dY1kB1/5)

Comment: I need back search...This will output "test" but I need "cite"

Comment: It is good. But if this is a string `This is a string with <xref cite@#>test2</xref> and 
<xref cite@#>test1</xref><xref cite@#>test</xref><xref cite@#>test1</xref>`  and regex `(?<=xref).*(?=@#>test1)` it gives output `cite@#>test1</xref><xref cite@#>test</xref><xref cite` (i.e.)it is extracted from "@#>test1" to last  "@#>test1" . So I think regex pattern won't be suitable for this requirement.

Comment: How can I get only first occurrence?

Comment: @Vidhya Raju I am glad to see accept my answer..  from `$matches` this array try to check by `var_dump($matches);`

Comment: Or use  `preg_match($re, $str, $matches);`

Comment: And one more query, If string is `<xref cite<e.g.>[p.11]@#>test</xref>` ,this regex `/(?<=xref)([\\w\\s]*)?(?=@#)/m` is only for words how to get all types of character. i.e. symbols,numbers etc

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to search backwards from a specified position, but an easy workaround is to just use `substr` to truncate the input at the desired position and then use `strrpos`:

```
$truncated = substr($str, 0, $start);
$end = strrpos($truncated, "xref ");
```

However, it looks like a regular expression could be a more convenient choice for this kind of not-quite-straightforward pattern matching.

Comment: substr can look from the end when given a negative starting position ( aka 2nd param )

Comment: @clockw0rk that doesn't help, because you need to tell it exactly how many bytes. But if you know that, you're no longer searching for anything, and that is a different proposition than the question above.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

> If the value is negative, search will instead start from that many characters from the end of the string, searching backwards.

So you can search backwards if you provide a negative number for the offset. This should work

```
$end=strpos($str,"@#>test");
$start=strpos($str,"xref ",$end-strlen($str)); 
$output=substr($str,$start, $end-$start);
```